# Reason of error on pointer de-referencing

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

Output is: `10` and it gives no error.

```
int main(){
    int j=10;
    int *i=&j;
    printf("%d",*i);
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives me an error:

```
int main(){
int *i;
int j=10;
*i=&j;
printf("%d",*i);
return 0;
}
```

I understand that pointer de-referencing is causing the error. But how is that happening?

Comment: Indent your code and compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: Hasn't a similar question been asked a couple of days ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This defines `i` as an `int *` and sets its value to the address of `j`:

```
int *i=&j;
```

This defines `i` as an `int *`, then tries to *set what `i` points to* to the address of `j`:

```
int *i;
int j=10;
*i=&j;
```

The final `*i = ...` is trying to *dereference* an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using an uninitialized pointer.
Your `*i = &j` should be `i = &j`

Answer (score 0):

`i` **itself** is declared as a "pointer to `int`". So you should write `i = &j;` to assign it with the address of `j`.

In your case, `*i = &j` dereferences it before the assignment, that is, the value of a pointer is assigned to an `int`, which resides in a legal or illegal memory block, because `i` is uninitialised.

Note that accessing an uninitialised variable causes undefined behaviour, not to mention accessing the object an uninitialised pointer points to.

Answer (score 0):

> `int *i=&j;`

Here you're declaring `i` to be a `int *`, and assigning the address of `j`.

> `*i=&j;`

In this case, though, you've already declared `i`, and you're assigning `&j` to the location that `i` points to rather than to `i` itself. So that's one error. Another is that `i` doesn't point to anything yet because you haven't initialized it. If you want `i` to point to `j`, you should drop the `*`:

```
i = &j;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple declaration, with initialization, of an integer variable `i`:

```
int i = 10;
```

Normally it is very easy to split up the declaration and the initialization:

```
int i;
/* ... */
i = 10;
```

That's fine.  But the syntax of pointer declarations in C is unusual, and it leads to a little bit of asymmetry when working with declarations and initializations.  You can write

```
int *i = &j;    /* correct */
```

But if you split it up, the `*` does not tag along, because it was part of the declaration.

```
int *i;
/* ... */
i = &j;         /* right */

*i = &j;        /* WRONG */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *i;
```

You've declared `i` as a pointer to `int`, but you haven't set it to point *to* anything yet; the value of `i` is *indeterminate*<sup>1</sup>.  It will contain some random string of bits that (most likely) does not correspond to a valid address<sup>2</sup>.  Attempting to dereference `i` at this point leads to *undefined behavior*, which can mean anything from an outright crash to corrupted data to working without any apparent issues.

The line

```
*i = &j;
```

has *two* problems, the first one being that `i` doesn't point anywhere meaningful (and this is where your runtime error is undoubtedly coming from; you're attempting to access an invalid address).  The second is that the *types* of `*i` and `&j` don't match; `*i` has type `int`, while `&j` has type `int *`.

---

1. Variables declared locally to a function without the `static` keyword have *automatic storage duration*, and are not implicitly initialized to any particular value.  Do not assume that any such variable is initially set to 0 or `NULL` in the absence of an explicit initializer.  Variables declared outside of any function body or with the `static` keyword have *static storage duration*, and those variables will be initialized to 0 or `NULL` in the absence of an explicit initializer.

   "Valid" meaning the address of an object defined within your program (i.e., another variable, or a chunk of memory allocated via `malloc`, etc.) or a well-known address defined by the platform (such as a fixed hardware input address). `NULL` is a well-defined *invalid* address that's easy to test against.